# How to show the 0 in the pivot tables (Syncfusion Framework) in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, pivot, pivot-table, syncfusion

I am using the Syncfusion pivot tables for showing the percentage values. When I am showing the zero values it was showing the null or empty values.

[Syncfusion pivot table](https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/pivot-table)

Instead of showing null values need to replace the zero values.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion has already logged your requirement as an improvement task and it will be available in the 2019 Volume 1 release which is planned at the end of March 2019. You can track the same by using the following link.
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/3234/show-the-null-value-as-zero-custom-value-in-pivot-table

The 2019 Volume 1 Beta release was planned by next week with this feature included, you can check on that too.